# Dibujar funciones f(x) con JavaScript y canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Mi idea es pintar una **función de x** usando **JavaScript** y **Canvas**, he estado mirando por internet y no he encontrado nada al respecto, puede que haya buscado mal, no lo se, pero la cuestión es que no tengo muy claro como empezar, aquí abajo dejo lo que llevo hasta ahora intentado:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    //Establezco una escala que posteriormente aplico
  var scale = 100;

  var cv = document.getElementById("fx");
  cv.height = windowHeight;
  cv.width = windowWidth;

  var ctx = cv.getContext("2d");

   //Aquí traslado todo el contexto al centro de la pantalla
  ctx.translate((windowWidth / 2),(windowHeight / 2));

//Esta función simplemente dibuja los ejes (es lo de menos)
  drawaxis();
  function drawaxis() {

    var x_axis = {
      x: -windowWidth / 2,
      y: 0,
      xf: windowWidth / 2,
      yf: 0
    }

    var y_axis = {
      x: 0,
      y: -windowHeight / 2,
      xf: 0,
      yf: windowHeight /2
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x_axis["x"],x_axis["y"]);
    ctx.lineTo(x_axis["xf"],x_axis["yf"]);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(y_axis["x"],y_axis["y"]);
    ctx.lineTo(y_axis["xf"],y_axis["yf"]);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

  }

//Aquí es donde empiezan los inconvenientes (que más abajo detallo)
  for (x = -windowWidth; x <= windowWidth; x = x + 0.01) {
    var y = Math.pow(x,2);
    drawfx(x,y);
  }

//Pintar los puntos para pintar los valores
  function drawfx(x,y) {

//Aquí es donde aplico la escala
    x = x*scale;
    y = y*scale;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<!-- El tamaño del canvas lo cambio en el script -->
  <canvas id="fx" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

**Hecho esto, el resultado es más o menos decente, quedando tal que así:**
[image]

El problema de hacerlo de este modo es que hasta que el loop **for** no finaliza, la gráfica no se pinta y esto provoca un ligero tiempo de espera hasta que todos los valores son calculados.

Y el segundo problema está en (como bien se puede apreciar en la imagen) que al ser en este caso una función exponencial a medida que aumentan los valores los puntos están cada vez más separados y por esta razón **la "línea continua" comienza a ser "discontinua"**.

Y ahora bien, mi pregunta está en si ésta es una manera más o menos decente de hacerlo o si hay maneras mucho mejores de hacerlo que me estoy perdiendo.......

Agradecería cualquier ayuda posible. ¡Gracias!

Comment: Podrías probar con `window.requestAnimationFrame(function() { drawfx(x,y); });` para ver si así dibuja en forma paulatina.

Comment: Con [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/requestAnimationFrame) siempre dibujará, eso es un hecho ya que es prácticamente un loop infinito de alto rendimiento. Por otro lado, ¿has pensado en usar [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) para ésto? Te simplificaría las cosas bastante, además tiene un método `update` para actualizar en demanda la gráfica. Mira [ésta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086575/chart-js-draw-mathematical-function) pregunta.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía siempre dibujará, pero hay un delay implícito entre cuadro y cuadro que podría permitir ver como la curva se va trazando. Es más elegante que usar un window.setTimeout con timeout cero.

Comment: @GustavoGarcía retiro lo dicho. Probé con rAF y no dibuja la curva. Al parecer esa técnica sólo tiene sentido redibujando el canvas completo en cada frame :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es graficar funciones matemáticas en todo el sentido de la palabra, esta librería es para ti http://mathjs.org/index.html

```js
function draw() {
    try {
      functionPlot({
        target: '#plot',
        data: [{
          fn: document.getElementById('eq').value,
          sampler: 'builtIn',  // this will make function-plot use the evaluator of math.js
          graphType: 'polyline'
        }]
      });
    }
    catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      alert(err);
    }
  }

  document.getElementById('form').onsubmit = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    draw();
  };

  draw();
```

```css
 input[type=text] {
      width: 300px;
    }
    input {
      padding: 6px;
    }
    body, html, input {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      font-size: 11pt;

    }
    form {
      margin: 20px 0;
    }
```

```html
<title>math.js | plot</title>
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mathjs/3.10.0/math.min.js"></script>

  <!-- load http://maurizzzio.github.io/function-plot/ -->
  <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.5/d3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://wzrd.in/standalone/function-plot@1.14.0"></script>
  
<form id="form">
  <label for="eq">Enter an equation:</label>
  <input type="text" id="eq" value="4 * sin(x) + 5 * cos(x/2)" />
  <input type="submit" value="Draw" />
</form>

<div id="plot"></div>

<p>
  Plot library: <a href="https://github.com/maurizzzio/function-plot">https://github.com/maurizzzio/function-plot</a>
</p>
```

Comment: Tremendo :D *as always* :)

Comment: gracias hermano! :D estamos para servir :D

Comment: Gracias @fredyfx !

Comment: de nada @Javi, dale con todo el power!

Comment: @fredyfx jajajajja, lo haré!

Answer (score 1):

Podrías usar [p5.js](https://p5js.org) para hacer las curvas, algo así:

```
function draw() {
    // Acá van los cálculos para obtener los puntos
    // p5.js tiene funciones matemáticas, así que te
    // Podrían ser útiles

    beginShape(); //Para empezar a dibujar la figura
    vertex(x, y); // Para añadir vértices
    curveVertex(x, y); // Vértices para hacer curvas
    endShape(CLOSE); // Para terminar de dibujar
    // El parámetro "CLOSE" es opcional, y sirve
    // Para cerrar la figura.
}
```

Te sugiero que leas la [Documentación](https://p5js.org/reference).

Espero te sea útil!

Answer (score 0):

Primero, **sí te estás complicando de más**, porque existe [fooplot](http://fooplot.com) para generar exactamente lo que buscas.

Segundo: pensé que usando requestAnimationFrame se podría dibujar gradualmente. Me equivoqué en eso. No sabría cómo mostrar el dibujo progresivamente.

Tercero, para el tema de la línea discontinua, en vez de dibujar circulitos de 1px de radio, debieras dibujar una línea, como en la hipótesis de Riemann. La línea va de (x,y) a (x + dx, y + dy).

```
var interval = 0.01;

for (x = -windowWidth; x < windowWidth; x = x + interval) {
    drawfx(x, interval);
}

function drawfx(x,interval) {
    var x0 = x,
        y0 = Math.pow(x0,2),
        x1 = x + interval,
        y1 = Math.pow(x1,2);

    x0 = x0*scale;
    y0 = y0*scale;
    x1 = x1*scale;
    y1 = y1*scale;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var windowWidth = window.innerWidth;
  var windowHeight = window.innerHeight;

    //Establezco una escala que posteriormente aplico
  var scale = 100;

  var cv = document.getElementById("fx");
  cv.height = windowHeight;
  cv.width = windowWidth;

  var ctx = cv.getContext("2d");

   //Aquí traslado todo el contexto al centro de la pantalla
  ctx.translate((windowWidth / 2),(windowHeight / 2));

//Esta función simplemente dibuja los ejes (es lo de menos)
  drawaxis();
  function drawaxis() {

    var x_axis = {
      x: -windowWidth / 2,
      y: 0,
      xf: windowWidth / 2,
      yf: 0
    }

    var y_axis = {
      x: 0,
      y: -windowHeight / 2,
      xf: 0,
      yf: windowHeight /2
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x_axis["x"],x_axis["y"]);
    ctx.lineTo(x_axis["xf"],x_axis["yf"]);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(y_axis["x"],y_axis["y"]);
    ctx.lineTo(y_axis["xf"],y_axis["yf"]);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();

  }

var interval = 0.01;

for (x = -windowWidth; x < windowWidth; x = x + interval) {
  drawfx(x, interval);
}

function drawfx(x,interval) {
    var x0 = x,
        y0 = Math.pow(x0,2),
        x1 = x + interval,
        y1 = Math.pow(x1,2);

    x0 = x0*scale;
    y0 = y0*scale;
    x1 = x1*scale;
    y1 = y1*scale;

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.moveTo(x0, y0);
    ctx.lineTo(x1, y1);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
}

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
<!-- El tamaño del canvas lo cambio en el script -->
  <canvas id="fx" width="0" height="0"></canvas>
</div>
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación también @amenadiel